# Kolmogorov Consistency and {0,1}

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I start with $\Omega=\{0,1\}$ with probability measure $P(0)=1/2$ and $P(1)=1/2$. Consider the infinite product $\{0,1\}^\mathbb N$ and associated $\sigma$ algebra. Now, this product is the interval $[0,1]$. How do I show that the product sigma algebra is the Borel sigma algebra and the product measure,(obtained through Kolmogorov consistency) is the Lebesgue measure? Does the ergodic theorem (on the left shift) apply?

Comment: The product is not *literally* $[0,1]$; the point is that there is a bijection with $[0,1]$ such that the resulting pushforward measure under this bijection is the Lebesgue measure. Anyway, to prove that I think I would want to use some machinery, rather than trying to operate directly. Specifically I would want to show that if $X_i$ are iid Bernoulli(1/2) variables then $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{-i} X_i$ is uniformly distributed. This should be doable using, for instance, characteristic functions.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks

Comment: I tried that, any tricks to evaluate the infinite product?